# Programming without "finally"

Tags: php, try-catch-finally

I don't have the required version of PHP that supports `finally`, so I am wondering if this:

```
try {
    work();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    cleanup();
    throw $e;
}

cleanup();
```

is **exactly** the same as

```
try {
    work();
} finally {
    cleanup();
}
```

Comment: `cleanup()` is just in case a fault occurs, or it runs to the finish, failures occurring or not?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I want the behavior to be the same as in the `finally` block, so yes - it should run whether an exception is thrown or not (and if one is thrown, it should propagate to the caller).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the `finally` block is to execute regardless of what happens in the `try` block, or in following `catch` cases. So if you think about it, the code in the finally block is executed either after a successful `try` block execution, or after any exception was thrown. So if you write it just as you did in your solution, then you do indeed mimic the situation exactly. If there is no exception, the code after the `try/catch` structure is executed; and if there is an exception—any exception—you also execute it.

I think the only situation which the `finally` support may rescue you from, which your version inherently can’t, is when you are actually aborting the outer execution stack early. For example if this code is inside a function and you are returning from within the `try` block, then the `finally` would still be executed, but in your manual implementation it of course couldn’t.

So if you make sure that you do not leave early, then yes, it should work in the same way.

There are not many ways to leave a function early that don’t throw an exception; `return` is the most obvious and aborting the program with `exit`, `die` or similar would be another.

Comment: Oh, so as long as there is no call to like `return` or `exit` then it's OK?

Comment: @uk4321 Clarified that a bit, but yeah, that should be all you need to look out for. And if you do need to do something like that, you will have to work with some state variables that take care of skipping parts of the code etc., so you don’t accidentally execute code you normally wouldn’t.

Answer (score 4):

Finally code blocks execute always - if there's an exeption, and if there isn't. But if you catch an exeption and do `cleanup()` after catch block, then yes - it's basically the same thing.

Comment: That's why I put the `// cleanup` after the `try` block too... I'll put it as a function call to make it clear.

Comment: The comments in OP’s code are supposed to be the actions that are inside the block. Given that `cleanup` is done in both the catch block and after the try/catch, it should be the same, no?

Comment: From the comments in the original code, what uk4321 posted is the same.

Comment: Sorry, only saw the cleanup in catch block. Yes, if so it's basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

> In PHP 5.5 and later, a finally block may also be specified after the catch blocks. Code within the finally block will always be executed after the try and catch blocks, regardless of whether an exception has been thrown, and before normal execution resumes.

If you look at the examples, you'll notice that the `finally` block will always execute even if the exception is caught. However, when there is an exception, the code will not resume, so the `finally` block is a good way to ensure that certain lines of code are always executed even if there is an exception.

The `finally` block will matter if your `catch` block uses a `return` function or something like that. Otherwise, there is no difference between putting your cleanup in the `finally` block or after your `try/catch`

Here's the example in question from the doc comments:

> Just an example why finally blocks are usefull (5.5)

```
<?php

//without catch
function example() {
  try {
    //do something that throws an exeption
  }
  finally {
    //this code will be executed even when the exception is executed
  }
}

function example2() {
  try {
     //open sql connection check user as example
     if(condition) { 
        return false;
     }
  }
  finally {
    //close the sql connection, this will be executed even if the return is called.
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: So what is the answer to my question?

Comment: @uk4321 edited and answered with example from the documentation comments for an example of a useful `finally` block

Answer (score 0):

### Generally, yes.

Most of times, both examples work equivalently:

```
<?php
function work_success() {
    echo 'working' . PHP_EOL;
}

function work_fail() {
    echo 'working with fail' . PHP_EOL;
    throw new Exception('exception');
}

function cleanup() {
    echo 'cleanup' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Code without `finally`:

```
try {
    work();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    cleanup();
    throw $e;
}
cleanup();
```

Code with `finally`:

```
try {
    work();
} finally {
    cleanup();
}
```

Results when `work = work_success` for both `finally` and non-`finally` versions:

```
working
cleanup
```

Results when `work = work_fail` for both `finally` and non-`finally` versions:

```
working
cleanup
Exception: exception
```

### However, there are caveats.

Like @poke said, using your examples together with control flow mechanisms might get funny results. Here's an illustration of this using simple `return` statement:

```
function test()
{
    try {
        return 'success';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        cleanup();
        throw $e;
    }
    cleanup();
}

echo test();
```

This will output just `success`. `cleanup()` won't get fired unless an exception is thrown. According to prior examples, equivalent `finally` counterpart to above example would look like this:

```
function test()
{
    try {
        return 'success';
    } finally {
        cleanup();
    }
}

echo test();
```

Note that this **will** execute `cleanup()` regardless of any exceptions, so the output will be:

```
cleanup
success
```

For some people it's suprising that code in `finally` block is executed prior to `return` statements. As long as you are aware of this, there should be no problems.